# Where is Alice?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Apparently I have to find Alice, because she has gone missing and you can't have a trial without a defendant (or so says the Queen, and I am going to take her at her word, because I don't want her to threaten to cut my head off again...)

Problem is, I have searched all over and I can't find her. The Cheshire Cat mentioned something about the Bizarre Room holding the answer or something to that effect, but I have searched that room (both while tiny, and while regular-sized), and don't see Alice (or anything else helpful), just a bunch of enemies to fight.

Where is Alice? Do I need to find her? If not, what do I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haha, so this is what throws everyone off. Alice is not there. You do have to go to the bizarre room though. You'll need to fight the Trickmaster, which is the last battle before you are finished with Wonderland.

I tried to find a good video but I really couldn't. So I'll list out the steps you need to do, but they may be hard to understand so let me know if you need clarification. Optional things are indented further

- Go to the bizarre room and defeat the heartless
- Touch the lamp to light it (I don't remember if this is optional or not)

  - Go through the painting to get back to the lotus room
  - Get items from the flowers
  - Go back to the bizarre room
- Hit the latch on the shelf so the teddy bear falls

  - Go through the doors near the ceiling
  - Turn on the faucet (for some dalmatians)
- Go all the way back to the bizarre room from the castle (right side up)
- Drink the potion to grow big
- Move the teddy to make the clock pop out
- Move the clock
- Shrink and go through the entrance that you just revealed
- Go through the tea party area to the house at the back and go through the door
- Fight the heartless on the ceiling and light the lamps there
- Go back to the castle area (and save)
- Fight the final boss for Wonderland

  - If you're having trouble beating him:

    > Fire increases his damage; Blizzard is better.

How this did not come up in user testing, I will never know, but this is how you beat Alice in Wonderland. I assure you, this is by far the most confusing part of the game.

Answer (score -1):

Get all the clues, present them to the queen, fight her cards and tower. Go back into forest, all the way back to the right is an entrance to the tearoom. Go through there and into the bizarre room. Light the two flames then find the exit back to the queens room. This is all you have to do. Now back to the regular bizarre room. Scene with Cheshire cat and boss fight. End.